# Filter redux store item array for duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have following reducer:

```
case INIT:
  return {
    ...state,
    items: [...state.items, ...action.payload],
  };
```

I need somehow to check if in `state.items` array are items from action.payload array and do not include them in `state.items`. I have such a code:

```
[...state.items.filter(item => item !== action.payload)],
```

but it doesn't what I need, it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What data types do you reference in `state.items` and `action.payload`? Objects or primitive types?

Comment: it is strings..

Comment: ```[...state.items.filter((item) => item !== action.payload)]``` what array does your code return for this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle that with primitive types is using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
case INIT:
    return {
        ...state,
        items: [...new Set(state.items.concat(action.payload))],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the `payload`.

```
case INIT:
      const { items } = state;
      const newItems = action.payload.filter(item => !items.includes(item))]
      return {
        ...state,
        items: items.concat(newItems),
      }
```